# Remote interface exposed from both ends of a single upnode connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, dnode

So I know how to splice a dnode interface in from both ends of TCP connection - see my code here: [client.js](https://github.com/jpillora/node-king/blob/7ed513714557e758fa0df44d52f61e11bf7fc5cf/proto/dnode-client.js) and [server.js](https://github.com/jpillora/node-king/blob/7ed513714557e758fa0df44d52f61e11bf7fc5cf/proto/dnode-server.js). Can you do this with **upnode** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally figured it out:

[client.js](https://github.com/jpillora/node-king/blob/97586d148535949cb9e7c8ffc93c12d30e50623a/proto/client.js)

[server.js](https://github.com/jpillora/node-king/blob/97586d148535949cb9e7c8ffc93c12d30e50623a/proto/server.js)